# How to represent different business facts in a single fact table?

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse, star-schema, fact-table

I have the following dimensional tables:

- DimUser
- DimClient
- DimLocation
- DimDate
- DimTime
- DimLog
- DimStatuses

How could I represent the following events in the fact table?

1. Logs by user over time
2. User status change over time

Let's say the fact table is something like this:

| application_id | location_id | user_id | client_id | log_id | date_id | time_id | status_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 19 | 3 | 2 | 69 | 45 | 64 |  |
| 1 | 23 | 1 | 1 |  | 10 | 207 | 1 |

Is it a valid representation where the first record refers to a log event and the second record refers to an user status change?

Comment: If the status was the same in both records - you should not leave empty cells. Also, if the log was the same at both points in time - you should not leave empty cells in the fact table. Each record in the facts table represents the knowledge about each and every dimension at the given point in time. Ideally, there should be no empty cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different facts should be represented in the schema under different fact tables. For this case, there should be a fact table for logs by user and another fact table for user status change over time, this is known as a galaxy schema or multi fact schema, so in other words it should look like this:

[image: Galaxy schema with user status change over time and logs by user fact tables]

So, it's feasible because you can create your measures according your grain.

- Number of users by application (user status change over time fact
  table)
- Number of logs or events by user (logs by user fact table)
- Active/Inactive users (user status change over time fact table) user
- logs over time (logs by user fact table)

Answer (score 1):

Every measure needs to have its grain defined. If 2 measures have the same grain then they can, but don’t have to, be stored in the same fact table. If 2 measures don’t have the same grain then they can’t be stored in the same fact table